# Specify a dependency with latexmk and -output-directory

Tags: latexmk, pythontex

I'm using `pythontex` and I call `\pyc{import * from functions}`.  This works fine, but when I used `-output-directory`, I need `functions.py` to get copied to the specified `$out_dir` before the build begins.

I've tried using `add_cus_dep`, but can't get that to work (and it also doesn't feel like the right solution).  Any suggestions?